# To find words but only with requested number of specific letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script that supposed to find words that contain given letters by user has input.
The script works however not exactly in a way I want.
For example if I input letters:stop
The scripts prints out words I have input but are repeated such like: stop, stoper, stereotype.
There shouldn't be the word: "Stereotype" because I've input only only one: "e" and "t

```
letters = input('letters: ')
words = open('newwords').read().splitlines()

#print (words)
print(".......................")

for word in words:

     if all(x in word for x in letters):
        for x in letters:
            if word.count(x) == letters.count(x):
                print(word)
```

Comment: There is no "e" in your input "stop".

Comment: yes, you're right my bad, had other word in example as well.
But the point is it supposed to print words in which appear letters: "s","t","o","p", then it supposed to print: "stop","stoper", etc but not "stereotype" unless I input: "s","t"o","p","t" or "s","t","t" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your 'newwords' look like. I try something like this:

#### test.txt:

```
stop
stoper
stereotype
```

the code is same as yours except `words = open('test.txt').read().splitlines()`

#### Output:

```
letters: stop
.......................
stop
stop
stop
stop
stoper
stoper
stoper
stoper
stereotype
stereotype
stereotype
```

Your `for x in letters` check one letter at a time. As there is same count for "s", "o" and "p", stereotype is printed three times (not four because of different count for "t") .

#### Suggestion:

You may change your last part to this so the word only printed out after all letter count is checked.

```
for word in words:
    if all(word.count(x) == letters.count(x) for x in letters):
        print(word)
```